# duck (CyberDuck CLI) with google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, cyberduck

I'm trying to get the [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) [CLI (duck.sh)](https://duck.sh/) to work interfacing with a google drive (not "Google Cloud Storage") and I'm having problems getting the oAuth authorization to work.   I [found this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438616/how-to-access-google-drive-from-cli-cyberduck) but it's out of date - as the newer versions of Cyberduck do absolutely work with Google Drive.  Using the regular cyberduck GUI I can browse and operate on my G-drive instance, but I can't quite ***quack the code*** (sorry!) for how to make this work using the CLI.

```
[lwobker:~]$ duck -l googledrive://<user>@gmail.com/                   
Authenticating as <user>…
OAuth2 Authentication. Paste the authentication code from your web browser.
Authentication Code: <pasted pass here>

Save password (y/n): n
Disconnecting www.googleapis.com…
Login failed. Malformed auth code. Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.
```

I've tried a number of different URLs, including:
@gmail.com
me@gmail.com@www.googleapis.com
and a couple of others.

I also can't seem to figure out where the GUI version of cyberduck stores it's authorized credentials... if I could re-use those that would be fine, doing a one-time setup at the beginning doesn't break my use case.

I'm somewhat familiar with the [Google Developers API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard), and I've created one for use with this project, but I can't seem to figure out how the Google "Client ID" and other credentials map to the Cyberduck tool.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention/19766913#19766913
In response to "Authentication code" you say "pasted pass(word)" which of course is not an Authentication code

Comment: Cyberduck saves passwords in the login keychain (macOS) or the credential manager (Windows). You will find OAuth Tokens saved as `Google Drive (<user>@gmail.com) OAuth2 Access Token`

Comment: You will *not* need to register your own client in the Google API developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you paste the auth code obtained from the Google login page opened exactly as is without any line breaks. More information is available in the [wiki](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/googledrive).